# MongoDB group slowing down the query

Tags: mongodb, performance, facet, group

Let me explain the data structure first. I have 3 collections to store information about datamodels (products)

1. datamodel - one document for each distinct datamodel
2. release - Each data model can be applicable to multiple platforms/releases. Release collection will have one document for each platform, release, data model combination.
3. datatree - Each data model can contain multiple nodes. DataTree collection will contain one doc for each node in a datamodel.

**Fields of datatree:**

**id**- It is an xpath. Every data model has nodes of distinct id.

**nodehash**- This value is a hash of all properties of the node. If two nodes have the same nodehash it means it has the same properties. If two nodes have different nodehash it means that something has changed.

**base-type**- This value tells the node type (module/container/leaf,etc.)

All collections are interrelated through mod_id field.

**Requirement:**
While comparing two releases (1.3.0 and 1.8.1) of a platform(BXR), I would like to get the list of all datamodels and the statistics stating how many nodes and leaves have been added, deleted, modified.

I have broken this requirement to two pieces. The first query gets all datamodels for both releases of platform. It leaves the datamodels which are not changed across the two releases. It provides a remaining list of modified model's ids. I will now use these ids in the second query.

**Logic used**

1. If we are comparing release 1.3.0 and 1.8.1, we know the mod_ids which are available in 1.3.0 and 1.8.1 which are modified
2. Pull all the nodes related to 1.3.0 and 1.8.1
3. Add them to 2 buckets. fromMod bucket if node is present in 1.3.0 release or toMod bucket if present in 1.8.1 release
4. Compare the fromMod and toMod for each node

- 4a. If node has only fromMod, it has been deleted
- 4b. If node has
  only toMod, it has been added
- 4c. If node id has both fromMod and
  toMod but node hash has changed, it has been modified.

5. Now group and count the number of added, deleted and modified node in each data model

**Expected output:**

```
    {
      "modelX":{
        "nodeCount":{
          "added": 1,
          "deleted": 1,
          "modified": 1
        },
        "leafCount":{
          "added": 1,
          "deleted": 1
        }
      },
      "modelY":{
        "nodeCount":{
          "modified": 1
        }
      }
    }

}
```

**Implemented solution for query 2**
https://mongoplayground.net/p/MDnJrw1TuQG

**Doubts**

1. The query takes around 22 seconds to complete. Is there a better way to query this?
2. How to combine the results into the required format?
3. Is it better to finish the requirement using a single query? Is it okay to break it to 2 queries??

*Thank you for having the patience to read it completely* :)

Comment: How many docs in each collection and do you have indexes on those fields that you intend to perform `$match`?

Comment: release - 310 docs, datamodel - 2.1k docs, modelTree - 1.3m docs. Yes, I have indexes for mod_id field